# Como agregar a una tabla una consulta mysql sumada y agrupada

Tags: php, mysql

lo que requiero es que en una tabla me muestre la suma de un campo que esta agrupado:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS cnt FROM produccion group by producto  ";



          <!-- Tabla donde se listará la consulta -->
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="100">ID</th>
                <th width="250">Producto</th>             
                <th width="200">CNT</th>
                <th width="200">SUMA</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <!-- Generamos el listado vaciando las variables de la consulta en la tabla -->
              <?php

              while($persona = $consulta->fetch_assoc()) //Creamos un array asociativo con fetch_assoc

              {

              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['id']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $persona['producto']; ?></td>           
                  <td><?php echo $persona['cantidad']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $persona['SUMA']; ?></td>
                  <td style="width:150px;">

                    </td>
                </tr>

              <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres sacar la suma total del campo "cantidad?

Comment: si pero de cada item los registros van agrupados por productos

Comment: Coloca la estructura de tu tabla para poder ayudarte.

Comment: depronto no me expliqué bien, lo que requiero es que el resultado de la consulta  el cual tiene un campo cantidad que ya esta sumado en la consulta se muestre en una tabla html

Comment: Entiendo. Agrega todo el codigo donde estas haciendo la consulta, y la vista donde haces el recorrido.

Comment: LISTO ya modifique el codigo de la pregunta ya lo puedes ver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu consulta estas haciendo de la funcion `SUM(cantidad)` y le colocas un alias `AS cnt` entonces para obtener el resultado de la suma tienes que imprimir el alias

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(cantidad) AS cnt FROM produccion group by producto";

    <!-- Tabla donde se listará la consulta -->
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th width="100">ID</th>
                    <th width="250">Producto</th>             
                    <th width="200">CNT</th>
                    <th width="200">SUMA</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <!-- Generamos el listado vaciando las variables de la consulta en la tabla -->
                  <?php

                  while($persona = $sql->fetch_assoc()) //Creamos un array asociativo con fetch_assoc

                  {

                  ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $persona['id']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $persona['producto']; ?></td>           
                      <td><?php echo $persona['cnt']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $persona['SUMA']; ?></td>
                      <td style="width:150px;">

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
```

Comment: Pero claro,! me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agual mil gracias

Comment: Vale suerte....